# Events, Sets and How They're Related.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

When someone says,

$$\textit{"what is the set of all possible outcomes of rolling a die?"}$$

I can understand what they mean.

$$S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$$

Or when some says an event is, 
 $$\textit{"rolling a number less than or equal to four, what is the corresponding set"}$$

I can appreciate they mean the set,

$$E = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$$

But its when people say for instance, $\textit{'there is at least k people in a line'}$, I get confused.

1. How do you represent such an event as a set?
2. How would you define set operations like union, intersection and subset on such an event?

Comment: This just mean "more or equal than $k$ people", it is represented by $$\{k,k+1,\ldots\}\cap\Omega$$ where $\Omega$ is the set of all possible outcomes.

Comment: If there is at least $k$ people in a line, then if $k=10$ is it possible for there to be $2$ people in the line?

Comment: @Masacroso It is not clear what the sample space is.,  if the sample space was $\{1,2,3,\dots\}=\{\text{all possible numbers of people who can stand in a line}\}$ then I would agree, however it is entirely possible that the sample space here is instead $\{\text{all possible arrangements of people in a line}\}$ where (Billy,Bob,Alice) is a different arrangement than (Alice,Bob,Billy,Charles,Andrew) and both of those are elements of the sample space among potentially a huge number of others.

Comment: In that case, the event "there are at least $k$ people in a line" would correspond to the set $\{x~:~x~\text{is an arrangement of people in a line and the arrangement contains at least}~k~\text{people}\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How do you represent such an event as a set?

The same principle can be applied.   If $S=\Bbb N=\{0,1,\ldots\}$ is the set of counts for people in the line, then $E=\{\omega\in S: \omega\geq k\} = \{k, k+1,\ldots\}$ is the set of counts where at least $k$ people are in the line.

2. How would you define set operations like union, intersection and subset on such an event?

Just use the standard set operations.

Comment: Oh right, that makes question 1. really clear, thanks!

For question 2, what if we stuck in a second line in the question with at least j people. 

What would it mean mathematically to take the intersection of line 1 (where there is at least k people) with line 2 (where there is at least j people)?

Comment: @Philip You would need to use a *different* sample space, one for which you could map outcomes to the counts of either line.  Such as $\Bbb N^2$.  Then the event you wish would be represented by: $$\{(x,y)\in \Bbb N^2: x\geq k, y\geq j\} = \{x\in\Bbb N: x\geq k\}\times\{y\in\Bbb N: y\geq l\}$$